# How to setup SSO between Wordpress and Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

My wordpress and magento is on different server.  Does anyone have idea on how to setup SSO between them both? I tried multiple solutions but those only works if having same domain,not if installed seperately.